# How to account for a lack of fit using a quasi-poisson on non-integer, overdispersed data

Tags: r, mixed-model, poisson-distribution, glmm

I am trying to run a mixed model on over-dispersed non-integer data. My data are not counts, but are zero-inflated and over dispersed. The variable is distance (how far a gps point is from a central location) and as such looks like: 0.33, 64.73, 5.2 etc. I have been using a quasi-Poisson distribution as I have read that quasi can handle non-integer data (both Poisson and negative binomial cannot). I am using the `glmmPQL` function in package MASS as this allows quasi distributions with a random term (the identity of the individual that the gps point comes from).The functions `glmm` and `lmer` do not work with a quasi-Poisson distribution. Plotting the residuals indicates a lack of fit of this model.log-transforming the data to try and make it normal before hand also fails (the Shapiro-test for normality is significant). I am unsure how to fix this, as I seemingly have to use a quasi-distribution (link="log") because my data is not counts, non-integer and not normal but there is still overdispersion and lack of fit when using this distribution.

My question therefore is: **How to model over-dispersed, non-integer data in a mixed model when quasi-Poisson does not seem to work?**

My code so far is:

```
summary(glmmPQL(distance_from_centroid~Chick.Juv.Adult+Summer_winter, 
                random=~1|markingnumber, family=quasipoisson(link="log"),
                data=centroid_distances))
```

Which results in:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by maximum likelihood
 Data: centroid_distances 
  AIC BIC logLik
   NA  NA     NA

Random effects:
 `Formula: ~1 | markingnumber
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.157381 2.136811

Variance function:
 Structure: fixed weights
 Formula: ~invwt 
Fixed effects: distance._from_centroid ~ Chick.Juv.Adult + Summer_winter 
                      Value  Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)       2.0670095 0.09403952 695 21.980221  0.0000
Chick.Juv.AdultC -0.2945360 0.06686399 695 -4.405002  0.0000
Chick.Juv.AdultJ -0.2005831 0.06727181 695 -2.981682  0.0030
Summer_winterW    0.1207721 0.04324588 695  2.792684  0.0054
 Correlation: 
                 (Intr) C.J.AC C.J.AJ
Chick.Juv.AdultC -0.565              
Chick.Juv.AdultJ -0.512  0.736       
Summer_winterW   -0.267  0.134  0.043

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.53759073 -0.48277169 -0.31041612  0.06314122  7.48672836 

Number of Observations: 1009
Number of Groups: 311
```

Which when plotting the residuals gives me:

[image: plot of residuals]

Answer (score 3):

There is not really such a thing as "over-dispersed data" in abstract. Over-dispersion means that the variability of the data is more than *expected*, and without a specific context there is no "expected" dispersion. An expected variability exists in just a few specific situations usually involving count data: for example, binomial sampling (number of successes out of n trials) and Poisson sampling (number of events over a period of time with a constant instantaneous event rate). For these settings one can derive the distribution, and it turns out that the variance is a function of the mean. For example, for binomial $E(X)=np$, and $Var(X)=np(1-p)$, while for Poisson $E(X)=Var(X)=\lambda$. So once you know the mean, you know what the variance should be. If you have count data that is generated by a Poisson-like sampling process with some deviations (eg individuals have their own event rate) and you find that $Var(X)>E(X)$, then you can talk of over-dispersion *relative to the Poisson distribution*.

You give no reason to think that the process generating the data resembles Poisson sampling (it is not even integer counts), so there is no reason why the variance should/could be equal to the mean or any other specific value, thus the concept of "over-dispersion" does not apply. There are lots of two-parameter (or more) distributions that can model mean and variance separately. Since your data seems to be positive and skewed, perhaps the gamma distribution would work (if the log-normal did not). There are lots of other possible approaches for modeling your data, just forget about the straight-jacket of the Poisson distribution when it really does not apply.